# Aid with Some Code: Initalizing Variables

Tags: c++

I am having issues with my code and I had forgotten to get help until now. This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

enum planetType { Mer, Ven, Ear, Moon, Mars, Jup, Sat, Uran, Nep, Pl };

void GetUserInput(string & pInput, double & pWeight);
void OutputWeight(planetType, double);
planetType ConvertInputToPlanetType(string);

int main()
{

    string pInput;
    planetType planet;
    double pWeight;

    GetUserInput(pInput, pWeight);
    OutputWeight(planet, pWeight);
    planet = ConvertInputToPlanetType(pInput);

    void GetUserInput(string pInput, double pWeight); {

        cout << "Please enter your weight: \n";
        cin >> pWeight;
        cout << "Mercury, Venus, Earth, Moon, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto\n";
        cout << "Please enter what planet you are on: \n";
        cin >> pInput;

    }

    planetType ConvertInputToPlanetType(string & pInput); {

        if (pInput == "Mercury") return Mer;

        else if (pInput == "Venus") return Ven;

        else if (pInput == "Earth") return Ear;

        else if (pInput == "Moon") return Moon;

        else if (pInput == "Mars") return Mars;

        else if (pInput == "Saturn") return Sat;

        else if (pInput == "Uranus") return Uran;

        else if (pInput == "Neptune") return Nep;

        else if (pInput == "Pluto") return Pl;
    }

    void OutputWeight(planetType planet, double pWeight);

    {

        switch (planet) {

        case Mer:
            cout << "The weight in Mercury would be " << (0.4155 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Ven:
            cout << "The weight in Venus would be " << (0.8975 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Ear:
            cout << "The weight in Earth would be " << (1.0 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Moon:
            cout << "The weight in Moon would be " << (0.166 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Mars:
            cout << "The weight in Mars would be " << (0.3507 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Jup:
            cout << "The weight in Jupiter would be " << (2.5374 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Sat:
            cout << "The weight in Saturn would be " << (1.0677 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Uran:
            cout << "The weight in Uranus would be " << (0.8947 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Nep:
            cout << "The weight in Neptune would be " << (1.1794 * pWeight);
            break;

        case Pl:
            cout << "The weight in Pluto would be " << (0.0899 * pWeight);
            break;

        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It says that *pWeight* and *planet* are uninitialized and it won't run until those are fixed. Can anyone help me with this as I've tried a few things and nothing has worked? I'm unsure how I am to go about initialize things and it's confusing me quite a bit as I'm unsure what I am to add.

Comment: uninitialized literally means "does not have an initial value". So you fix that error by giving these variables a value before you start using them.

Comment: Ok, I got that though my issue is I'm unsure what it would want me to add. pWeight would be prompted to be added via the next block under the switch.

Comment: @FireradFieritis "_pWeight would be prompted to be added via the next block under the switch_" It would be prompted for, yes, but would not be assigned to (in addition: assignment is not equivalent to initialization). You never assign the value to it, but you read from the variable - that's undefined behavior, your compiler was trying to warn you about.

Comment: Ok, then what would I assign to it then as I am clueless at this point? I thought that it was being assigned through getting the cout command to prompt for the user to input things.

Comment: Would be nice but I have to use the school material which is, frankly, expecting me to learn this stuff in eight weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables by reference into your GetUserInput() function. Scope of setting those variables is only that function.

Comment: Is that not what I did by adding the string and double or am I missing something?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It should be void GetUserInput(string &pInput, double &pWeight)

Comment: I'm sure that helped at least along with Ian's suggestion to move one of the blocks below the other which seemed to help.

Comment: Half of it works. The *planet* variable still needs to be initialized and that's proving more tricky than the issue with *pWeight*.

Comment: edit your question with what your code looks like now

Comment: There we go. It's been edited. It ain't much but you can see an entire block was moved and your suggestion added.

Comment: Call OutputWeight() after setting planet = ConvertInputToPlanetType(pInput);

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean? Do you mean in the variable declarations? If so, moving that stuff around generates errors.

Comment: currently you have    

 OutputWeight(planet, pWeight);
 planet = ConvertInputToPlanetType(pInput);

Have you tried

 planet = ConvertInputToPlanetType(pInput);

    OutputWeight(planet, pWeight);

Comment: If you mean swapping them, it was generating more errors to do that.

Comment: alright so ive plugged your code into a compiler - theres a few errors an mainly your functions should declared outside of the main(). When implementing your functions you should get rid of the ; before { }

Comment: in case that doesnt make sense heres a link : https://onlinegdb.com/BJDNGXCFL

Comment: That's bizarre. It's still not working in the program I'm using even if it's working in the online tester you sent.

Comment: even just copying that code into your program? What are you using? try this one : https://onlinegdb.com/ryelUmRKU

Comment: Ah, there we go! You, sir, are a genius! I thank you very much for your help! I was struggling so much with this.

Comment: you should still very much try and find the small differences between what you wrote and what I changed.Seems like the issues were variables, their scopes, and function declarations. These are fundamental basics in programming. Don't focus on what was changed but why it was changed.

Comment: Will do! Thank you! I'm hoping to learn this stuff better in the next class I take. I think class wasn't very well taught, unfortunately. But thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of obvious errors, firstly GetUserInput does not return any values as the variables pInput and pWeight are passed by value not by reference, so the variables in main() stay uninitialized. You then call Output Weight before you assign planet by calling  ConvertInputToPlanetType.

Comment: That seemed to fix pWeight though planet is still an issue. I am unsure what to do there.

Comment: It needs to be initialized too at least.

Comment: Do you now do planet = ConvertInputToPlanetType(pInput) before OutputWeight(planet, pWeight)?

Comment: If you mean in the variable declarations, that just seems to make it worse as it generates more errors.